# Prove that the limit of a series, containing 1/{powers-of-2}, is not rational

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I have a series, $$x_n = \sum_{k=0}^n2^{-k^2-k}, \forall n \in N$$

I have to find it's limit and prove it is not in Q(it is not rational).

I tried to write it $x_n=1+\frac{1}{2^1*2^1}+\frac{1}{2^4* 2^2} + ... + \frac{1}{2^{n^2}*2^n}$ or $x_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^{k(k+1)}}$

I also observed that it might be convergent, because the general term converges to 0...

How should I proceed next?
I found out from some sources that I might get to a solution by writing down all the terms in base 2, but can't there be a different solution that does not involve writing the number in base 2??
Your help is very appreciated, so thank you!

Comment: "it is convergent because the general term converges to $0$" <- That is not sufficient for the convergence of the series. Considering the base-$2$ expansion is the easiest and quickest way to see that the sum is irrational.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that for surely it is not divergent. I was not paying too much attention, i will correct. Could you please detail the demonstration in base 2? Or better, could you tell me if this can be approached some other way?

Comment: Since "not divergent" is the same as "convergent", that doesn't change anything, you need more than just that the terms converge to $0$.

Comment: Yea, you're right. It's goddamnt late at me, working all day with math, so I'm pretty tired. Excuse me, please

Comment: Compare it to the geometric series $\sum 2^{-k}$ and the convergence is settled.

Comment: I corrected, again. Now it's good. I had in mind that if the general term does not converge to 0, then the series is for sure divergent. And it all mixed up in my head

Comment: My series is $\le$ that this one, so if this one is convergent, my series is too. But next? How do I find the limit?

Comment: I doubt you can find a closed form of the limit. But showing that it is irrational is easy. If $x$ is rational, what do you know about its expansion in any base $b$?

Comment: That is has a finite number of powers of b in it's construction or something like that?

Comment: Finite or - what? Consider $\frac{1}{3}$ or $\frac{1}{7}$ in base $10$ for something familiar.

Comment: SO, for those irrational = infinite number of decimals (in base 10) so I'd have to prove that in base 2 these numbers have an infinit number of powers of 2, right?

Comment: Every number, rational or irrational has either a finite number of digits after the "decimal" point or an infinite number. What characterises the rational numbers?

Comment: Finite number of digits.

Comment: No, periodicity...

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. 
It is easy to check that your series is convergent by comparison test. One could compare $\{2^{-n^2-n}\}^{\infty}_{n=0}$ to $\{2^{-n}\}^{\infty}_{n=0}$ i.e.
$2^{-n^2-n}\leq2^{-n}$ for all $n\geq0$ therefore
$$\sum^{N}_{n=0}2^{-n^2-n}\leq\sum^{N}_{n=0}2^{-n}=\frac{1-2^{-(N+1)}}{1-2^{-1}}$$
and as $N\to\infty$ then 
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}2^{-n^2-n}\leq\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}2^{-n}=\frac{1}{1-2^{-1}}=2<\infty$$
so the series converges.

Notice that the Jacobi theta function of second kind is defined as 
\begin{align}\nu_2(z,q)=\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty}q^{(n+1/2)^2}e^{(2n+1)iz}&=2\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}q^{(n+1/2)^2}\cos((2n+1)z)\\&=2q^{1/4}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}q^{n^2+n}\cos((2n+1)z)\end{align}
In this particular case $q=1/2$ and $z=0$. Thus the limit of the series is equal to 
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}2^{-n^2-n}=2^{-3/4}\nu_2(0,1/2)$$
Now $2^{-3/4}\notin\mathbb{Q}$ so it remains to check $\nu_2(0,1/2)$. I suspect it not to be rational neither a rational multiple of $2^{-3/4}$.

Answer (score 0):

If it were rational, the binary (or any other base) expansion would have to be eventually periodic.  For this series this is clearly not the case, as the gaps between the 1s become larger and larger.

- 'Eventually periodic' means that after some finite place in the expansion, the remaining part is periodic.